# Set dll paths in VC++ and vcpkg

Tags: visual-c++, vcpkg

I'm using vcpkg as library manager for my Visual C++ projects. Sometimes I link libraries dynamically and `vcpkg` provides dll's in `\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin` folder.
When I run project in `Debug` or `Release` mode I have error related to missing DLL. What is elegant way to organize Visual C++ to take dll's  from `vcpkg` folder?

Comment: You can set the `PATH` environment variable in Visual Studio Community for you debugging session in the debugger settings for your project.

Comment: I assume you are not using CMake for your Visual Studio projects. I ask because I believe it copies the dlls for you to the same folder as the executable.

Comment: I'm using standard Visual C++ build toolset and I'm interest in common practice while building with vcpkg support.